# Submit button call goes to locahost/default.aspx from localhost

Tags: iis, localhost

In Windows 7 machine:-
When i am on localhost page and click any submit button then it POST to localhost.

In Windows XP machine:-
When i am on localhost page and click any submit button then it POST to localhost/default.aspx.

Is it any OS related issue or IIS related?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your on windows machine setting.please go start button then find iis (Internet Information system manager) then check default Document. I have screen shot so please find it.may this will help you
[image]